# Fetching input back after OR of two inputs

Tags: math, input, logic, output, xor

I have two numbers A and B. I do following action.

A   OR   B   =  Output.

Now how can I get number B from Output and A i,e

?Output      ?      ?A     =   B

Answer (score 0):

Since (1 or 0 = 1) and (1 or 1 = 1),

There is no general relation to find B. You can only find B if A=0 then B=OUTPUT.